# Is there a way to stop 'child exited with status 1' error when running st -e 'curl wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R'?

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to get a script to open a new [`st`](https://st.suckless.org/) terminal window and execute `curl -s wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R`.

`st -e "curl wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R"` opens the terminal window briefly, but closes and returns `child exited with status 1` in the parent window.
I don't want to have to make a command in /local/bin just to make that request.
Is there a better way?

Comment: You tagged this bash, but the `st` command is not part of bash, and that command is crucial to being able to answer the question. Where is it coming from?

Comment: (in particular, we need to know how `st` works; if, for example, it treats all its arguments after `-e` as a single argument vector, then you might need something like `st -e sh -c 'curl wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R'`; but that's a big "if" / unfounded guess; the question really should be extended so it includes enough foundation on which to write a confidently correct answer).

Comment: From `man st`:
       -e command [ arguments ... ]
              st executes command instead of the shell.  If this is used it must be the  last  option
              on  the command line, as in xterm / rxvt.  This option is only intended for compatibil‐
              ity, and all the remaining arguments are used as a command even without it.

Comment: Then the suggestion in my earlier comment was appropriate. `curl wttr.in | less -R` is not a single command that can be run; it's a _script_. `curl` is a command, `less` is a command, `sh` is a command (that can take a script as an argument).

Comment: BTW, is the location hardcoded or is it coming from a variable? If it's coming from a variable, there are some changes that ought to be made to avoid the security problems I was referencing.

Comment: ...btw, the best way to thank someone for answering your question is to click the checkbox next to the answer. (I notice you haven't done that on any historical questions either).

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

Well-designed terminal programs take argument vectors that can be invoked directly with `execve()` (or the newer `posix_spawn()` family of syscalls), not shell commands for invocation with `system()`. This makes them easier to use securely, avoiding the need to quote and escape contents to be passed as arguments into a single shell command (where without that escaping one is vulnerable to injection attacks). Some legacy terminals take `system()`-ready `sh` strings (at least for compatibility), but you're using software from https://suckless.org/ -- they've taken it on themselves to do better.

---

#### The Short/Simple/Insecure(?) Fix

The terminal you're using takes a command and argument list after `-e` *as separate arguments*. Therefore, you want something like:

```
st -e sh -c 'curl wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R'
```

Here, `sh` is the command to run in the terminal, `-c` is its first argument, and `curl wttr.in/LOCATION | less -R` is its second argument.

---

#### Doing This Securely

If your location is coming from a variable, however, then you should keep it out-of-band from the content passed as a script:

```
location="wttr.in/LOCATION"
st -e sh -c 'curl "$1" | less -R' sh "$location"
```

Here, your script `curl "$1" | less -R` is run with a `$0` of `sh` (used in error messages to describe the name of the program that failed; change it however you like) and a `$1` of `wttr.in/LOCATION`. Passing the URL in `$1` means that a URL containing a string like `$(rm -rf ~)` won't delete your home directory, as it might with less incautious approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response. Is it okay to play fast and loose with the security if the variables I intend to use are defined in the same script?

Comment: If they're hard coded instead of based on filenames, user input, &c, that does give you a lot more latitude. I'd still suggest not _using_ that latitude, though: using sound practices habitually means you're still covered when someone copies your code into a program that _does_ accept user input, or a future version of you is asked to make it more parameterizable. And being in good habits even when it doesn't matter helps make sure you're following those same habits when it does.

Comment: (One of the most expensive data loss incidents I've personally been present for happened because someone assumed filenames in a given directory couldn't even include anything but hex digits, when the directory was only writable by in-house code that was built to enforce that assertion; then they added a second, still in-house, tool that could write to the directory -- it was in Python, but used a C library with a buffer overflow bug; that bug dumped garbage including a whitespace-surrounded `*` into the variable used for the filename, and the script with the assumption deleted everything)

Comment: ...moral of that story is that Murphy's Law is alive and well, and it's better to write robust/secure code defensively since you don't know all the weird things that can happen in the real world. (And that one was random chance; attackers trying to take advantage of data with a privilege boundary between its producer and consumer happens too).